# adding a temporally column in gridview in c#

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I want to add a temporary column to devexpress gridview without adding this column to corresponding table in the database.I mean that this column only for view. how can I do that. thanks

Comment: Please provide some more details, also source-code to let us know the context.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this task with easy via the [Unbound Columns](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/1477/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Unbound-Columns) feature:

```
gridView1.Columns.Add(new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn() {
    Caption = "TMP", 
    FieldName = "tmp", 
    UnboundType = UnboundColumnType.String,
    Visible = true 
});
```

Related info: [GridColumn.UnboundType](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn.UnboundType.property)